# Looping JSON Images - On Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, arrays, json, advanced-custom-fields

I am calling an API into WordPress via Advanced Custom Fields with a CPT Vehicles. All populate appropriately when calling my function, I have 22 fields based on the JSON response which i then create a post with. I need each IMAGE URI in a seperate field However my ImagesURI only pulls in the 16th Ranked ImageURI into every IMAGE URI. This is my code, I have created a Foreach Loop to access the array within the array of the JSON, There is 16 images roughly per car.

```
    $response = json_decode($json_data, true);
                foreach ($response as $index => $car) {
                    $car['BasicPrice'];
                    $car['BodyStyle']['BodyStyle'];
                    $car['Colour'];
                    $car['EngineNumber'];
                    $car['EngineSize'];
                    $car['FuelType']['FuelType'];
                    $car['HasServiceHistory'];
                    $car['IsNew'];
                    $car['InternetPrice'];
                    $car['IsReserved'];
                    $car['Make']['Make'];
                    $car['Model']['Model'];
                    $car['Odometer'];
                    $car['PhotoCount'];
                    $car['PreviousOwners'];
                    $car['RegistrationNumber'];
                    $car['RetailPrice'];
                    $car['Specification']['Doors'];
                    $car['StockNumber'];
                    $car['Transmission']['Transmission'];

                    foreach ($car['Images'] as $images ) {
                        $images['ImageURI'];

                    }

                }


            if (!is_array($response) || empty($response)) {
                return false;
            }


$car[] = $response;

foreach ($car[0] as $car) {

    $vehicle_slug = sanitize_title($car['Colour'] .'-'. $car['Make']['Make'] . '-' . $car['Model']['Model'] . '-' . $car['StockNumber']);

    $existing_car = get_page_by_path($vehicle_slug, 'OBJECT', 'Vehicle');

    if ($existing_car === null) {

        $inserted_car = wp_insert_post([
            'post_name' => $vehicle_slug,
            'post_title' => $vehicle_slug,
            'post_type' => 'Vehicle',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        ]);

        if (is_wp_error($inserted_car)) {
            continue;
        }

        $fillable = [
            'field_5d665d2055d00' => $car['BasicPrice'],
            'field_5d665d2a55d01' => $car['BodyStyle']['BodyStyle'],
            'field_5d665d3155d02' => $car['Colour'],
            'field_5d665d3955d03' => $car['EngineNumber'],
            'field_5d665d4255d04' => $car['EngineSize'],
            'field_5d665d4c55d05' => $car['FuelType']['FuelType'],
            'field_5d665d5055d06' => $car['HasServiceHistory'],
            'field_5d679b5c4a0de' => $images['ImageURI'][0],
            'field_5d67f07329f3b' => $images['ImageURI'][1],
            'field_5d67f4dfeb0dd' => $images['ImageURI'][2],
            'field_5d665d5755d07' => $car['IsNew'],
            'field_5d665d6255d08' => $car['InternetPrice'],
            'field_5d665d6c55d09' => $car['IsReserved'],
            'field_5d665d8955d0a' => $car['Make']['Make'],
            'field_5d665d9255d0b' => $car['Model']['Model'],
            'field_5d665d9855d0c' => $car['Odometer'],
            'field_5d665da055d0d' => $car['PhotoCount'],
            'field_5d665da955d0e' => $car['PreviousOwners'],
            'field_5d665db155d0f' => $car['RegistrationNumber'],
            'field_5d665db855d10' => $car['RetailPrice'],
            'field_5d665dc055d11' => $car['Specification']['Doors'],
            'field_5d665dc755d12' => $car['StockNumber'],
            'field_5d665ddc55d13' => $car['Transmission']['Transmission'],


        ];

        foreach ($fillable as $key => $car['BasicPrice']) {
            update_field($key, $car['BasicPrice'], $inserted_car);
        }
    } else {

        $existing_car_id = $car['StockNumber'];
        $existing_car_newer = get_field($car['StockNumber'], $existing_car_id);


        if ($car['StockNumber'] >= $existing_car_newer) {
            // Update Our Post Meta
            $fillable = [
                'field_5d665d2055d00' => $car['BasicPrice'],
                'field_5d665d2a55d01' => $car['BodyStyle']['BodyStyle'],
                'field_5d665d3155d02' => $car['Colour'],
                'field_5d665d3955d03' => $car['EngineNumber'],
                'field_5d665d4255d04' => $car['EngineSize'],
                'field_5d665d4c55d05' => $car['FuelType']['FuelType'],
                'field_5d665d5055d06' => $car['HasServiceHistory'],
                'field_5d679b5c4a0de' => $images['ImageURI'][0],
                'field_5d67f07329f3b' => $images['ImageURI'][1],
                'field_5d67f4dfeb0dd' => $images['ImageURI'][2],
                'field_5d665d5755d07' => $car['IsNew'],
                'field_5d665d6255d08' => $car['InternetPrice'],
                'field_5d665d6c55d09' => $car['IsReserved'],
                'field_5d665d8955d0a' => $car['Make']['Make'],
                'field_5d665d9255d0b' => $car['Model']['Model'],
                'field_5d665d9855d0c' => $car['Odometer'],
                'field_5d665da055d0d' => $car['PhotoCount'],
                'field_5d665da955d0e' => $car['PreviousOwners'],
                'field_5d665db155d0f' => $car['RegistrationNumber'],
                'field_5d665db855d10' => $car['RetailPrice'],
                'field_5d665dc055d11' => $car['Specification']['Doors'],
                'field_5d665dc755d12' => $car['StockNumber'],
                'field_5d665ddc55d13' => $car['Transmission']['Transmission'],


            ];

            foreach ($fillable as $key => $car['BasicPrice']) {
                update_field($key, $car['BasicPrice'], $existing_car_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call my function It populates the three Images fields I have as a test but with the Same URL. How can I loop over so it registers each 'ImageURI'serperately Thank you in advance!

Below is my JSON:

```
{
    "BasicPrice": 4995.83,
    "BodyStyle": {
        "BodyStyle": "3 DR",
        "BodyStyle_UID": "4cf50fe2-8c3f-e611-80cb-0a94ef0355af"
    },
    "Colour": "Red 'n' Roll",
    "DaysInStock": 1029,
    "DaysInStockGroup": 1029,
    "Discount": 0.00,
    "EngineNumber": "B12XER-19MV2339",
    "EngineSize": 1229,
    "EstimatedDeliveryDate": "2016-11-04T00:00:00",
    "FuelType": {
        "FuelType": "Petrol",
        "FuelType_UID": "9cd0d601-bb1f-409d-b04d-4255ff47dc85"
    },
    "HasServiceHistory": false,
    "Images": [
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 1,
            "Image_UID": "2088e32e-d46a-42c2-8412-3802743bcc06",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=1&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 2,
            "Image_UID": "590cdfa2-d791-4414-bbb4-e5fbe7a5ac80",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=2&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 3,
            "Image_UID": "038674d1-f32e-40ac-90bf-fad4d3b25e7f",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=3&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 4,
            "Image_UID": "9e4d36b0-7e9d-4159-9315-548e30835aa4",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=4&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 5,
            "Image_UID": "c3ad8b52-df16-4925-b8f2-6434a1d3ece6",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=5&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 6,
            "Image_UID": "b5e66c41-a76e-4cd2-a535-623715e19961",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=6&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 7,
            "Image_UID": "6ce8cb63-4cee-4451-abd6-abc367d9f1d2",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=7&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 8,
            "Image_UID": "7b5ecc82-b8ea-4af4-85d6-1ab13c527edf",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=8&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 9,
            "Image_UID": "a1b2dae3-342f-4917-b7d8-6d9135bb8966",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=9&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 10,
            "Image_UID": "a6e1fce8-7bf9-4570-898b-91aa368c889d",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=10&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 11,
            "Image_UID": "0587afe6-4d95-4ce3-b571-0c1bc894516f",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=11&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 12,
            "Image_UID": "5b4713c8-37c9-4702-937c-4938c95bbee9",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=12&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 13,
            "Image_UID": "6c6a83d9-0782-42c6-a1fe-2d14272c7832",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=13&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 14,
            "Image_UID": "6e8a2171-e85a-4afd-a4fb-e70eeab38d10",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=14&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 15,
            "Image_UID": "f60e84ab-91bf-494d-9a54-0ad27615135a",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=15&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        },
        {
            "Entity_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
            "ImageNumber": 16,
            "Image_UID": "bfe311ca-4a62-4518-b27f-4d1473386741",
            "ImageURI": "https://vehiclestock-public.pinnacledms.net/ViewVehiclePhoto.aspx?BUID=a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af&VUID=8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af&Rank=16&Width=960",
            "ImageWidth": 960
        }
    ],
    "Interior": {
        "Interior": "",
        "Interior_UID": "05f50fe2-8c3f-e611-80cb-0a94ef0355af"
    },
    "IsNew": false,
    "InternetPrice": 0.00,
    "IsQualifying": true,
    "IsReserved": false,
    "Location": "Autospray",
    "Make": {
        "FranchiseModel": null,
        "Make": "Vauxhall",
        "Make_UID": "ac84ccae-882d-e611-80ca-0a94ef0355af"
    },
    "ManufacturerRecommendedRetailPrice": 0.00,
    "Model": {
        "Make_UID": "ac84ccae-882d-e611-80ca-0a94ef0355af",
        "Model": "Adam",
        "Model_UID": "cb34d5c0-5c3f-e611-80cb-0a94ef0355af"
    },
    "Odometer": 13582,
    "Options": [],
    "OrganisationalUnit": {
        "Address": {
            "Address1": "Blackhouse Circle",
            "Address2": "Blackhouse Industrial Estate",
            "Address3": "",
            "Country": null,
            "County": "Aberdeen",
            "PostCode": "AB42 1BN",
            "PostTown": "Peterhead"
        },
        "Description": "Gillanders Motors Ltd.",
        "EmailAddress": "email@gillanders.co.uk",
        "OrganisationalUnit_UID": "a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af",
        "ParentOrganisationalUnit_UID": "51a9312b-1462-4b7c-aee3-319d6d86ecec",
        "Telephone": "01779 479777"
    },
    "PhotoCount": 16,
    "PhysicalLocation": {
        "DealerCode": "",
        "Description": "Gillanders Motors Ltd.",
        "LocationDescription": "Autospray",
        "OrganisationalUnit": {
            "Address": {
                "Address1": "Blackhouse Circle",
                "Address2": "Blackhouse Industrial Estate",
                "Address3": "",
                "Country": null,
                "County": "Aberdeen",
                "PostCode": "AB42 1BN",
                "PostTown": "Peterhead"
            },
            "Description": "Gillanders Motors Ltd.",
            "EmailAddress": "email@gillanders.co.uk",
            "OrganisationalUnit_UID": "a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af",
            "ParentOrganisationalUnit_UID": "51a9312b-1462-4b7c-aee3-319d6d86ecec",
            "Telephone": "01779 479777"
        },
        "UID": "a3db2a66-b4fb-4ac2-a78a-0f042aab50af"
    },
    "PreviousOwners": 0,
    "Profiles": [
        {
            "Description": "Long Term Loan",
            "UID": "fe8b7140-87e0-4784-88b1-d607865be492"
        }
    ],
    "RegistrationDate": "2016-10-31T00:00:00",
    "RegistrationNumber": "SW66 EZH",
    "RetailPrice": 5995.00,
    "Specification": {
        "Doors": 0,
        "Specification": "Jam",
        "Specification_UID": "8795a7e0-e1a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af"
    },
    "Status": 0,
    "StockNumber": "U1211",
    "Transmission": {
        "Transmission": "5 Speed Manual Petrol",
        "Transmission_UID": "707ad700-1318-4e57-88aa-6fb19e58f6d0"
    },
    "UnitOfDistance": 0,
    "Vehicle_UID": "8be4d43d-e3a4-e611-80cf-0a94ef0355af",
    "VehicleCode": "VAAD12JAM3HPIM                          ",
    "VehicleType": 1,
    "VideoCount": 1,
    "Videos": [
        {
            "Identifier": "GxobtgbP1yc",
            "UploadedDate": "2016-11-14T13:39:07.543",
            "User": null,
            "User_UID": "ef891044-ce8a-489f-bddf-cea4511c3c52",
            "Video_UID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
            "VideoURL": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/GxobtgbP1yc?showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&autoplay=0&autohide=1"
        }
    ],
    "VIN": "W0L0MAP08G6082024"
},
```

Comment: Before posting a Question, you should take care to write a MRE (Minimal, Reproducible Example, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), for example removing unuseful details, to allow people who takes care to answer to focus on the real issue...

Comment: What are all the `$car['***'];`-rows and the `$images['ImageURI'];` suppose to do? You're not passing it to a function or storing it in any variable. Those rows and your loops are completely pointless since you're not actually _doing_ anything in them.

Comment: Didnt want to put to much code into this question, I will add more of my code. Thanks for your advice

Comment: $car['**] Allows me to call my json data to wordpress advanced custom fields. This works however my '$images['ImageURI'];' seems to only fetch one value from each car

Comment: Those rows doesn't allow you to do anything you wouldn't be able to do without them. Just writing a variable on it's own doesn't do anything at all. If you remove the variables from your loops, you would still get the exact same result. Also, after the loop, the the `$car`-variable will only contain the last record of your response.

Comment: And your check: `if (!is_array($response) ...)`  should go _before_ you're trying to iterate through it using `foreach`. Otherwise, you would get a warning about invalid argument supplied for foreach if the response isn't an array.